# delete any cluster with an empty list

Tags: python, list

IF I have a list of data that I create it by

```
dictlist = []
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        dictlist.append(temp)
        dictlist
```

so the results:

```
dictlist [[0, array([4, 5, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int64)], [1, array([], dtype=int64)], [2, array([ 7, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19], dtype=int64)], [3, array([10, 12], dtype=int64)]]
```

dictlist consists of cluster label and the objects that belong to this cluster, for example, cluster (0) consists of objects number (4,5,6,8,9), and cluster (1) has no object and so on.

my question is how can I delete any cluster with an empty list like cluster 1.

so the result will be

```
dictlist [[0, array([4, 5, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int64)], [2, array([ 7, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19], dtype=int64)], [3, array([10, 12], dtype=int64)]]
```

Comment: What is `mydict`?

Comment: By saying "has no object", does that imply the array is empty? If so, why not just check whether the array is empty before adding it to the list?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution that replaces your entire code with a single line:

```
dictlist = [[k, v] for k, v in mydict.items() if v.size > 0]
```

Thus you can build your desired result from scratch, without having to modify an intermediate result

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in order to filter the data:

```
new_dictlist = [d for d in dictlist if len(d[1]) > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for all, your answers help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Say dictList is the input list as you mentioned. You have to check whether the array is empty. If empty, then remove that item from the list.

```
dictlist = [[0, [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]], [1, []], [2, [7, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19]]]
for item in dictlist:
  arr = item[1]
  if(len(arr) == 0):
    dictlist.remove(item)
    
print(dictlist) # prints [[0, [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]], [2, [7, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object numbers are stored in a numpy arrays, you can use:

```
print([d for d in dictlist if not d[1].size == 0])
```